# Does Granger causality also tells me how big the time lag is?

Tags: time-series, lags, granger-causality

I want to determine how big the time lag is for two time series.
In this example, how long the twitter sentiment about a stock leads the stock price.
I use Python with statsmodels.tsa.stattools grangercausalitytests.
The granger causality matrix provides values:

```
Granger Causality
number of lags (no zero) 1
ssr based F test:         F=5.0057  , p=0.0420  , df_denom=14, df_num=1
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=6.0784  , p=0.0137  , df=1
likelihood ratio test: chi2=5.1966  , p=0.0226  , df=1
parameter F test:         F=5.0057  , p=0.0420  , df_denom=14, df_num=1

Granger Causality
number of lags (no zero) 2
ssr based F test:         F=2.4270  , p=0.1339  , df_denom=11, df_num=2
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=7.0603  , p=0.0293  , df=2
likelihood ratio test: chi2=5.8484  , p=0.0537  , df=2
parameter F test:         F=2.4270  , p=0.1339  , df_denom=11, df_num=2

Granger Causality
number of lags (no zero) 3
ssr based F test:         F=1.4153  , p=0.3079  , df_denom=8, df_num=3
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=7.9611  , p=0.0468  , df=3
likelihood ratio test: chi2=6.3863  , p=0.0943  , df=3
parameter F test:         F=1.4153  , p=0.3079  , df_denom=8, df_num=3
```

The lags represent days. Is it possible to determine the length of the time lag with Granger? So here, Ccn I say that the leading time series is 3 days ahead because the p values are the largest in this example?